# Mongo lookup to return local even when foreign not matched

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let say i have `User` collection and a user can have many `Books`.

I want to query `User` and then lookup to get `Books` data, with specific `userId` and `bookId` but when if that user don't have `Books`, still return the User data with empty books or null.

**Mongo: 3.4**

What I tried.

```
$this->mongo->selectCollection('users')->aggregate([
    ['$match' => ['userId' => $userId]],
    [
        '$lookup' => [
            'from' => 'books',
            'localField' => 'userId',
            'foreignField' => 'userId',
            'as' => 'books'
        ]
    ],
    ['$unwind' => [
        'path' => '$books',
    ]],
    ['$match' => ['books.bookId' => $bookId]]
]);
```

**Problem:** with above code, it will return empty result when book is not matched. I still want to get user data.

**Sample result I expect are:**

When book found

```
user : {
    userId: 1
    name: xxx,
    books: {
        name: Book name
        userId: 1
    }
}
```

When book not found

```
user : {
    userId: 1,
    name: xxx,
    books: null or whatever
}
```

Comment: In the last match you comparing bookId to userId which makes no sense to me. Remove the stage and you will have all users, even the ones without books.

Comment: @AlexBlex sorry that was a typo while creating simple example its `['books.bookId' => $bookId]`

Comment: You need to use `$filter` aggregation here to match with the `bookId` you will pass. or you can use `$lookup` 3.6 syntax with pipeline.

Comment: Remove `$unwind` and `$match`  and use this stage `['$addFields' => [
    'books' => [
      '$filter' => [
        'input' => '$books',
        'as' => 'book',
        'cond' => [ '$eq' => ['$book.userId', bookId]]
      ]
    ]
  ]]` after `$lookup`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet  it worked, thanks. You have small typo it should be `['$$book.userId,`   double $. Please post as answer so I accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation to filter the `books` array.

```
$this->mongo->selectCollection('users')->aggregate([
  [ '$match' => ['userId' => $userId]],
  [ '$lookup' => [
    'from' => 'books',
    'localField' => 'userId',
    'foreignField' => 'userId',
    'as' => 'books'
  ]],
  [ '$addFields' => [
    'books' => [
      '$filter' => [
        'input' => '$books',
        'as' => 'book',
        'cond' => [ '$eq' => ['$$book.userId', bookId]]
      ]
    ]
  ]]
])
```